# Add custom Attachment Display Setting for images

Tags: posts, images, attachment-fields-to-edit

I've been doing a lot of research and I've yet to work this out. Can you add in a custom option in the `Attachment Display Settings` (part of `Insert Media` dialog in post editor)?

What I'm after is the ability to add an anchor with a class around all images in posts.

Comment: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com can do this, when you create a new field group for you extra field, choose the Attachment location and it will display the extra field in the Insert Media dialog and on the attachment edit page too

Answer (score 1):

This will add a field in the attachment edit screen for applying a class to the img tag.

```
function IMGattachment_fields($form_fields, $post) {
    $form_fields["imageClass"]["label"] = __("Image Class");
    $form_fields["imageClass"]["value"] = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_imageClass", true);
    return $form_fields;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_edit", "IMGattachment_fields", null, 2);
function my_image_attachment_fields_save($post, $attachment) {
    if ( isset($attachment['imageClass']) )
    update_post_meta($post['ID'], '_imageClass', $attachment['imageClass']);
    return $post;
}
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", "my_image_attachment_fields_save", null, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
/**
* Attach a class to linked images' parent anchors
* e.g. a img => a.img img
*/
function give_linked_images_class($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ) {
    $classes = 'img'; // separated by spaces, e.g. 'img image-link'

    // check if there are already classes assigned to the anchor
    if ( preg_match('/<a.*? class=".*?">/', $html) ) {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*? class=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $html);
    } else {
     $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" >', $html);
    }
    return $html;
}

add_filter('image_send_to_editor','give_linked_images_class',10,8);
```